# Extract Java7u60 Server on Windows

Tags: windows-7, java, tar, 7-zip

I've downloaded the file server-jre-7u60-windows-x64.tar.gz from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html and am trying to extract it with 7Zip.

I have done that successfully with all previous updates of Java 7, but for some reason update 60 fails.

The first step seem to work properly and creates a file of about 200MB in size named server-jre-7u60-windows-x64.

Then the next step only extracts a couple of files (total of 656 bytes) and stops.

Is that a problem with the archive or with 7Zip?  Any ideas on how to extract it properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem, the file was name server-jre-7u67-windows-x64.gz 
I just renamed it to server-jre-7u67-windows-x64.tar.gz (note the .tar) and it worked